# angular jasmine spyOn($window, 'addEventListener'); not work

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Can't understand why this code not work?

Error is:

```
Expected spy addEventListener to have been called with [ 'scroll', <jasmine.any(Function)>, true ] but it was never called.
```

.

```
describe('sessionActivity.spec', () => {
    beforeEach(module('sessionActivity'));

    it('should subscribe', inject(($window, sessionActivity) => {
        spyOn($window, 'addEventListener');

        sessionActivity.subscribe();
        //$window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {}, true);
        //$window.addEventListener('click', () => {}, true);
        expect($window.addEventListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith('scroll', jasmine.any(Function), true);
        expect($window.addEventListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith('click', jasmine.any(Function), true);
    }));
});
```

Inside a sessionActivity.subscribe I create two events listeners.

And also if I uncomment two lines with //$window.addEventListener all test is pass.

What I should change here?

**EDITED:**

The problem was that I used shortcut inside sessionActivity.subscribe():

```
const { addEventListener, removeEventListener } = $window;
addEventListener('scroll', trackActivityWithDebounce, true);
addEventListener('click', trackActivityWithDebounce, true);
```

Can some one explain this?

Comment: Please, provide all relevant code. Where exactly is `addEventListener` being called? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The jasmine toHaveBeenCalledWith is suppose to verify that the spyied function is called.

So the error message is saying, You are expecting the the method should be called but it actually not called.

I think you commented out the code or while test that function is not called.

```
  expect($window.addEventListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith('scroll', jasmine.any(Function), true);
```

I think the above line is creating the problem. You need to verify that the scroll is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
spyOn($window, 'addEventListener')
```

to

```
spyOn($window, 'addEventListener').and.callThrough();
```